# Setting up a Green Party email

Tags: email

How do I set up- what do I need to set up, a Green Party email? No one in our local party knows!

Gateshead Greens

Answer (score 1):

Go to Mailings in the black Admin Menu when you are in civicrm, click on new Mailing, then select the template and target group as per the instructions  here https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/email/what-is-civimail/